PHP Stripe subscriptions unique user identifier
The tool Im building can requires multiple subscriptions per user, the subscriptions can be the same service but with different configurations.
Im creating individual subscription items for each user subscriptions because I want each item to have config details in it's description in the check out.
The problem is I want to be able to  identify each individual subscription so I know which one to edit/cancel in the future.
I've tried using metadata on the item, product and price attributes (of which the api only accepts it under product) and the API doesnt accept lookup_key anywhere in the line item.
The metadata while accepted by the API never actually shows up in stripe or in the payment confirmed webhook (the metadata just shows up empty of line items)
$lineItems;
foreach ($cartItems as $job){
    SubscriptionJobs::createJobForPayment($job,$userId,$cartId,$transactionId);
    $jobId = $job->item_id;

    $item = [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency'      =>'usd',
            'unit_amount'   => $unitAmount,
            'product_data'  => [
                'description'   => $description, 
                'name'          => $subName,
                'metadata'    => ['job_id'=>$jobId],
                
            ],
            'recurring' => [
                'interval' => Carts::getPaymentFrequency($cartId),
            ],
        ],
        'quantity' => '1',
    ];
    $lineItems[] = $item;
};

$checkoutData = [
    'line_items'          => [$lineItems],
    'client_reference_id' => $cartId,
    'subscription_data'   => ['metadata' => [
        'cart_id'       => $cartId,
        'user_id'       => $userId,
        'transaction_id'=> $transactionId]],
    'mode'                => 'subscription',
    'success_url'         => $DOMAIN . '/success',
    'cancel_url'          => $DOMAIN . '/cancel',
];
if($userData->stripe_id != ''){
    $checkoutData['customer'] = $userData->stripe_id;
}else{
    $checkoutData['customer_email'] = $userEmail;
}

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($checkoutData);
dd($checkout_session);

return redirect($checkout_session->url);

I've tried using both metadata and lookup_key everywhere I can think of but they never seem to carry over to stripe on a line item.
Is there anyway to identify which subscription is which when creating them at checkout time?
Thanks

It looks like Subscription Items metadata is not directly supported on a Checkout Session creation call.
What you can probably do is, first store your metadata like {'price_id_1' => 'some_value'} on the subscription_data.metadata fields, then after the Checkout Session is paid (when you receive the checkout.session.completed webhook event), call an Update Subscription API and set metadata on the Subscription Item level here, using the metadata on the Subscription mapping with the price id on each item.
The challenge would be how to express your config details on the some_value in the Subscription object. A json-encoded string could work as a plain string value.

Thanks @orakaro, that is basically the idea I came up with, it's just a pain if there are multiple subscriptions at different prices in the same checkout I have to go and assign each of them an ID that aligns with a subscription at the right price. I'll go ahead and do that if no one else has a better solution
